# Can I write scala code in netbeans6.9.1?

Tags: scala, review, netbeans-6.9

Is it possible to write and compile Scala code in netbeans6.9.1?  I am a beginner to Scala programming, and am very much confused about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never actually tried to write Scala in Netbeans personally but according to Dick Wall the support for Scala in Netbeans is pretty much the best of breed among the main 3 IDEs (IntelliJ, Eclipse, and Netbeans).  I know that's just anecdotal but it's from a pretty trusted source who literally inserted a whole new section into his **Java** Posse podcast just so he can geek out over Scala.

This looks like a fantastic place to get you started. http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala

Comment: Oh well, thanks @Tim. I was just curious to know whether there is any support for Scala in netbeans, because I am pretty much used to netbeans.

Comment: Yeah, the support is there but still in Beta, as it were.  Despite that, it's apparently quite good.  I believe Dick Wall taught his recent training course on Scala using Netbeans.

Comment: Trust Dick! :) And "use Netbeans". (c) JavaPosse

Answer (score 4):

Yes, check out the [Netbeans wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala); Scala modules are experimental and under active development, so check the nightly builds. Also check out [ErlyBird](http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlybird/); it's an Erlang/Scala IDE based on NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used Scala with Netbeans 6.8. I tried using 6.9, but could not get it to work. 
If you can manage with NB 6.8, then you are in luck.

Note that even with 6.8, refactoring is not available. However, code completion works very nicely and that is sufficient for me. I hope that there is a more usable Netbeans plugin for Scala in the near future.

Of course, you need to install the Scala plugin after installing NB 6.8 to get anything to work. Instructions here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala68v1

Comment: The exact Scala built that worked for me is `scala-2.8.0.r22602-b20100720020114`. I have not exeprimented with others. If you have trouble, try this particular one. (You need to set `%SCALA_HOME%` to the directory of this installation.)